# Prove the set of all complex valued sequences $(y_1, y_2,\ldots)$ for which $|y_k|< 1/k$ is closed.

Tags: real-analysis

Good afternoon,

I need to prove that that the set $Y$ of all complex-valued sequences $(y_1, y_2,\ldots)$ for which $|y_k| ≤ 1/k$, $k \in \mathbb{N}$, is closed.  I have already proved that it is a metric subspace of $l^2$ (this was part (a) of the question), but I am struggling to prove that it is closed (i.e. it contains the limit of all sequences in $Y$ that converge in $l^2$).  I know that I can either prove it directly, or I could use a theorem stating that a subspace of a complete metric space is close if and only if it is complete, although they both amount to the same sort of proof.  Would anyone be able to help start me off in the right direction?

(My apologies for the terrible formatting, it's my first time posting here!)

Answer (score 0):

The metric in $\ell^2$ is given by $$d(x,y)^2=\sum_{n\geqslant 0}|x_n-y_n|^2$$

That $x^n\to x$ means then that for each coordinate $x^n_k\to x_k$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: I guess here I would have to use the definition of convergence in a metric space, that is a sequence {$y_n$} in a metric space is said to converge if for any $\epsilon >0$, there exists a positive integer N such that 

$n > N \to d(x_n, x)<\epsilon$

?